# Expanding DL in outlook

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

If we send a mail to a DL and at the other end that DL gets expanded(will show all the names in it). 
Does this causes a performance issue on the outlook server?

Comment: Consider reediting your question. What is a DL? What do you mean by outlook server? Exchange servers, Outlook.com servers any other mail servers ?

Answer (score 1):

DL is not expanded on the receiving side. DL is expanded when you send the message - the receiving server will have no idea what your DL contains. Expanding DL is not expensive - it is expensive to deliver messages to multipel recipients.